# How do I authenticate and validate a password?

Tags: php, validation, authentication

I don't really know even what questions to ask here. My problem statement is simple: I need to store a password on the DB with a salt, validate an entered password against the stored password, and authenticate the password using a random challenge word whenever a user tries to log on. I am using php/javascript.

In trying to figure this out, the problem I am having is that if I pass up a challenge word in an html form, then hash the entered password with that word, I can authenticate the password on the server, but I can not separate the password from the challenge word so I can validate it against the salted password on the DB. If I send the password to the server in the clear or hash it without a challenge word, I can validate it but now I can not reliably authenticate it.

I think I need a 2 way algorithm of some sort so I can encrypt it with a key, and then authenticate the key while validating the password. How do I do it? or if it can't be done then what should I be doing?

Comment: To be clear, the random challenge is meant to secure the password during transit? Or is an authentication mechanism to prove they are human or similar?

Comment: In an effort to try to figure this out, I looked at the source code for a php blog called "Geeklog - The Secure CMS". Lo and behold, they send their user passwords free and clear, and they use MD5 on the server to "encode" the password. So perhaps my question should have been "for what types of system should I implement password validation and authentication using salt and challenge word?"

Comment: also phpBB seems to send password free and clear. I guess I was over thinking the problem.

Comment: @majicbunnie Yes, I was thinking I needed to secure the password in transit using the challenge word. Then I would need a way to compare that with the salted password on the DB but there isn't any way to do that..

Comment: The solution provided by @David Schwartz appears to do what you wish, and the added layer of SSL would be good idea as well. Granted, you are correct that this may be overkill depending upon your situation. A simple SSL login system with hash(salt + password) on the backend may be quite enough for your level of security needs.

Answer (score 2):

Encrypting a password with client-side scripting is generally a bad idea. The proper way to do this is to use SSL.

Also, **never** store password in cleartext. If you **must** use a method like the one you describe above, hash the password twice: once for storing it in the database, another time for the two-way authentication.

Answer (score 0):

1. To store a password, generate a random salt. Store `HASH(password+salt)` and `salt`. (Either the server or the client can do this computation.)
2. To perform an authentication, the server looks up the `salt` and `HASH(password+salt)`. It then generates a random challenge and sends the salt and the challenge to the client.
3. On the client, prompt the user for the password. Compute: 
   `HASH( HASH(password+salt) + challenge)`. Send it to the server.
4. On the server, you already have `HASH(password+salt)` and you have `challenge`. So you can also compute: 
   `HASH( HASH(password+salt) + challenge)`. Compare this to what the client sent you. If they match, the password is correct.

Note that this is vulnerable to a MITM attack, so it should be used over a connection that is itself protected from a MITM, such as an SSL connection.

Comment: This sounds like I would want a 2 step login process: 1) user submits user name, server looks up user and sends salt and challenge 2) user enters password and submits.

Comment: There is no advantage to hashing the password on the client prior to sending it to the server.  This just needlessly complicates client code.

Comment: The advantage is that the server cannot give up the password. Servers frequently wind up logging passwords, for example, and those log files sometimes get compromised. If the server doesn't see the password, it can't log it or compromise it. (Whether that makes it worth the effort is another question.)

Comment: The only way a server would be logging a password is if it is logging all of the post variables from the login page.  Which takes time to setup, and is neither automatic nor supported with most standard server logging mechanisms.  In other words you have to go out of your way to do this.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz  so, a 2 step logon then?

Comment: @James: It depends what your requirements are. You specifically asked for a method that uses a salted hash and a challenge.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz actually I asked how to authenticate a password with a challenge word while at the same time validating the password that was stored with a salt. I apologize if I wasn't clear. It seems to me it can not be done. You either choose to authenticate with a challenge word and store it without a salt, or store the password with a salt and validate the password being sent in the clear, but you can't have both. I looked at source code from Geeklog and phpBB and both send password in the clear, which suggests that passwords are typically sent in the clear and stored on the DB with salt.

Comment: @James: It can certainly be done. For example, you can generate a public/private keypair, encrypt the private key with the password, and store the encrypted private key along with the public key. You send the client the encrypted private key and the challenge. You can then confirm the client decrypted the private key (and thus knew the password) by making them sign the challenge. There exist algorithms that meet almost any imaginable set of requirements.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz How would I do that in php and javascript? Is there some library I can install that will work in both php and javascript that will allow me to do this encryption/decryption? Can you post a link?

Comment: @James There are JavaScript implementations of [SRP](http://code.google.com/p/srp-js/) and [RSA](http://www.hanewin.net/encrypt/rsa/rsa.js) available. But I don't know of any specific packages that have all the pieces put together for you in both JS and PHP.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Sounds like a project then. :)  I'll look into those two and see what I can dig up. Thanks!